# Codeigniter session in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have developed a website in codeigniter and integrated wordpress for blog. My problem is if i logged in the site, i am not able to use the codeigniter session value in the wordpress blog.

In Codeigniter once i logged in i am setting the following session using codeigniter session.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('get_user_session', $auD);
```

Now i need to use the session in wordpress header file or index file. I tried the below code in wordpress.

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

I am not getting the above ci session values.

Comment: But our problem is that we'd need to see some code to be able to assist

Comment: Please provide error messages, reproduction steps, or some code snippets of where it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

CodeIgniter's [Session class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html):

`>> stores session information for each user as serialized (and optionally encrypted) data in a cookie`.

The values you set using `$this->session->set_userdata('key','value')` are not going to be present in the `$_SESSION` variable.

CodeIgniter also supports storing session content in a database.

You can use that configuration to retrieve the session data in your WordPress blog.

Answer (score 0):

Use COOKIES to get the session data.
Refer this link: https://thomashunter.name/blog/accessing-codeigniter-session-data-using-external-scripts/

```
require_once("config.php");
$cisess_cookie = $_COOKIE['ci_session'];
$cisess_cookie = stripslashes($cisess_cookie);
$cisess_cookie = unserialize($cisess_cookie);
$cisess_session_id = $cisess_cookie['session_id'];

$cisess_connect = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOSTNAME, MYSQL_USERNAME, MYSQL_PASSWORD);
if (!$cisess_connect) {
 die("<div class="error">" . mysql_error() . "</div>");
}
$cisess_query = "SELECT user_data FROM ci_sessions WHERE session_id = '$cisess_session_id' LIMIT 1";

mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DATABASE, $cisess_connect);
$cisess_result = mysql_query($cisess_query, $cisess_connect);
if (!$cisess_result) {
 die("Invalid Query");
}
$cisess_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($cisess_result);
$cisess_data = unserialize($cisess_row['user_data']);
print_r($cisess_data);
```

Answer (score -1):

I use the following code in wp-config.php and works for me.

Store session in Codeigniter in DB.

Codeigniter version 3.x.x

```
define('BASEPATH', 2021);
require_once(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'panel'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'application'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'config'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."database.php");
$cisess_cookie = $_COOKIE['ci_session'];

$cisess_connect = mysqli_connect($db[$active_group]['hostname'], $db[$active_group]['username'], $db[$active_group]['password']);
if (!$cisess_connect) {
    die("<div class='error'>" . mysqli_error($cisess_connect) . "</div>");
}
$cisess_query = "SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE id = '$cisess_cookie' LIMIT 1";

mysqli_select_db($cisess_connect,$db[$active_group]['database']);
$cisess_result = mysqli_query($cisess_connect,$cisess_query);
if (!$cisess_result) {
    die("<div class='error'>" . mysqli_error($cisess_connect) . "</div>");
}
$cisess_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cisess_result);
$session_data = $cisess_row['data'];

$return_data = array();
$offset = 0;
while ($offset < strlen($session_data)) {
    if (!strstr(substr($session_data, $offset), "|")) {
        throw new Exception("invalid data, remaining: " . substr($session_data, $offset));
    }
    $pos = strpos($session_data, "|", $offset);
    $num = $pos - $offset;
    $varname = substr($session_data, $offset, $num);
    $offset += $num + 1;
    $data = unserialize(substr($session_data, $offset));
    $return_data[$varname] = $data;
    $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
}
print_r($return_data);
exit;
```